# graph theory - clique graph

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to understand the concept of clique graph. So I found this [page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CliqueGraph.html). But I do not understand the example and what "graph intersection" is.

[image: example given in the page]

Can somebody explain to me why $K_4$ is a clique graph of $G$?

All I understand so far is that this particular graph $G$ has 4 cliques they are all $K_3$.

Comment: There is also [an entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_graph) in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have some collection of sets, the intersection graph of the sets is given by representing each set by a vertex and then adding edges between any sets that share an element. (Wikipedia has a nice picture in the [intersection graph article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph).)

The clique graph is the intersection graph of the maximal cliques.

As you note, $G$ has four maximal cliques.

Each of the four cliques shares at least one vertex with each of the other cliques, so in this case the intersection graph is complete.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you go through and circle all of the maximal cliques of $G$ (which, as you noted, are all $K_3$s). These will be the vertices of the clique graph. When two (or more) circles overlap at a vertex in the original graph, those vertices will have an edge between them in the clique graph.